# Defining my own tags in HTML

Tags: css, html, tags

I have a paragraph in my website in which I have to highlight few words. Instead of using div and a class, I used a tag which I name myself as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            highlight{
                background-color:#FFF176;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        A quick <highlight>brown</highlight> fox jumped over a lazy dog.
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [JSSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxygws01/)

It seems to work fine. But is there anything wrong with this? Is it okay if I use it for a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is alright to do that, I would suggest the following: https://jsfiddle.net/838Lrnwk/

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #high .highlight{
          background-color:#FFF176;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="high">
      A quick <a class="highlight">brown</a> fox jumped over a lazy dog.
  </p>
</body>
```

This would give the same effect; however, you can control what paragraph has the the effect in and all other tags like font,em, strong, etc and still retain the highlight.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a better method because it passes the HTML validation by W3 too.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in using custom tags. However, you didn't define the tags you used. Please see the links below to articles on proper ways to user custom tags/elements.

1. [Using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)
2. [Extending HTML by Creating Custom Tags](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/extending-the-html-by-creating-custom-tags--cms-28622)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution in a project, functionally it's ok but is advisable that you attach your tags with a common classname to define styles sheets (CSS), tags structures (HTML) and functionality (JavaScript) in differents source files.

I recommended you to put in a different file your CSS styles with a link-tag inside the head tag like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

In this pages you can learn much more about it:

[MDN Web Docs Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)